# How to echo some output(Radio buttons) on the same line

Tags: php, html, css

Due to label output is coming on the next line

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{ 
    echo  "<label for='A'> <input type='radio' class='muted pull-left' name ='radio' id='A' value=".$row['dis'].">&nbsp;".$row['dis']."</label>";             
}
```

Output should be :

```
Radio button 1   Radio button 2 .....  Radio button n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS given below in style tag

fieldset {

overflow: hidden

}

.some-class {

float: left;

clear: none;

}

label {

float: left;

clear: none;

display: block;

padding: 2px 1em 0 0;

}

input[type=radio],

input.radio {

float: left;

clear: none;

margin: 2px 0 0 2px;

}

Answer (score 1):

That's a CSS problem. Make the `<label>` tag `display:inline`.

Comment: it is printing all radio together and all names together

Comment: Label is an inline element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

Comment: .. and you know about the CSS rules used on that project?

Comment: the same as you

Answer (score 0):

As @cweiske said, CSS seems to be the problem. The output without any CSS changes should be inline yet your output seems to be in a block format https://jsfiddle.net/qam2sxy5/.
Try

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{ 
echo  "<label for='A' style="display:inline"> <input style="display:inline-block" type='radio' class='muted pull-left' name 
='radio' id='A' value=".$row['dis'].">&nbsp;".$row['dis']."</label>";             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the input inside the label. Furthermore, a radio button doesn't have a value. It's checked or not checked.

```html
<div class="row">
  <label for='A'>Label A</label>
  <input type='radio' class='muted pull-left' name='radio' value='A' id='A' />
  <label for='B'>Label B</label>
  <input type='radio' class='muted pull-left' name='radio' value='B' id='B' />
  <label for='C'>Label C</label>
  <input type='radio' class='muted pull-left' name='radio' value='C' id='C' checked />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you But i got the answer